# How can I modify Gutenberg 'core/columns' block to change min and max columns number?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Gutenberg 'core/columns' block has a ability to have from 2 to 6 columns:

[image: https://prnt.sc/p21jld]

I want to modify it's '[RangeControl](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/range-control/#usage-2)' component 'min' and 'max' attributes to 1 and 12 instead of 2 and 6

It seems that I need to use [BlockListBlock filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blocklistblock) but I cannot understand how can I get those 'min' and 'max' attributes here.

Comment: Did you find how to do it?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?